# Generate index with page numbers for PDF

Tags: pdf-generation

I have record sets for which I need to programmatically generate PDFs, similar to a phone book. At the end of the listing, I need to append an alphabetical index of entries which includes the page number on which each entry appears. How can I discover these page numbers while building the index? I haven't chosen a PDF library yet, as I'm waiting to see if any support this functionality.

Comment: Which language you are using to create pdf?

Comment: @Dev.ArunCC This is for a PDF-writing service; I haven't chosen a language because I haven't figured out which PDF generator implementation will work best for us.

Comment: But you have to incorporate this service some where rite? Once you decided then it will easy to find solution first of all you have to chose technology.